# Cupy `RawKernel` CUDA_ERROR_NOT_FOUND: named symbol not found [cupy]

Tags: cupy

I am trying to write a custom cuda kernel in python using cupy's `RawKernel`, however I keep getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/nfs/users/xxxxxxxxx/git/raw_kernel.py", line 32, in <module>
    null.compile()
  File "cupy/_core/raw.pyx", line 291, in cupy._core.raw.RawKernel.compile
  File "cupy/_core/raw.pyx", line 117, in cupy._core.raw.RawKernel._kernel
  File "cupy/cuda/function.pyx", line 275, in cupy.cuda.function.Module.get_function
  File "cupy/cuda/function.pyx", line 216, in cupy.cuda.function.Function.__init__
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 226, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleGetFunction
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_FOUND: named symbol not found
```

Even when I define an empty function that does nothing, I am not able to get past compilation

```
none = """
__global__ void none() {
};
"""
null = cp.RawKernel(none, "null")
null.compile()
```

I am using python 3.10.12 with cupy 12.2.0.
The cupyx's `jit.Rawernel` decorator works instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the function's symbol name as the `RawKernel` argument. Use `extern "C"` to avoid symbol name being mangled.

```
none = """
extern "C" __global__ void none() {
};
"""
null = cp.RawKernel(none, "none")
null.compile()
```

See https://docs.cupy.dev/en/latest/user_guide/kernel.html#raw-kernels for more details.

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't clear to me, indeed, what the name passed to `RawKernel` was used for.